# Issue with divs stacking beside each other

Tags: css

I'm having some issues with aligning 3 divs beside each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpprn/

I have a strong feeling it's in the syntax, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
#story-container {
    width: 700px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#story-left {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#story-center {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;    
}
#story-right {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #808080;

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containing elements don't add up to the width of the parent, `700px`.

This is because padding is added to the width of the children elements.

Therefore, `300px` + `10px` + `100px` + `10px` + `300px` != `700px`

You would either have to subtract the padding values from the widths, or use something like [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), which changes the box model of an element, thereby causing its `padding`/`border` properties to be calculated into its `width`/`height`.

> The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements. It is possible to use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not correctly support the CSS box model specification.
>
> **border-box**: The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.
>
> From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

I added the following to each element, though it actually wouldn't be needed on the middle element, `#story-center`, as it currently doesn't have any padding.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/VXe42/) - it works now  **<sub>- (red background added to display the parent container)</sub>**

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Stupid question deleted.

Thanks for the speedy response Josh. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user2924426 Actually, no, that wasn't a bad question. I updated the answer to address what `box-sizing` is though.

Comment: Haha I actually thought that was in there at the outset and I just missed it. In any case, thanks for the high quality answer.